# SEOmatic plugin override global title in individual template

Tags: templating, plugin-seomatic

I have problem whereby I can't override a single page's SEO by using a field, because the page has too many table rows in the database, due to being very field heavy. Don't ask.

So I'd like to manually override the global `<title>` that [SEOmatic](https://github.com/nystudio107/seomatic) produces in the individual template page. But haven't been able to get it to work from the docs, as I'm just producing a second title tag.

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the `SEOMatic Meta` fieldType?

What I do is create a field of this field type and assign it to the entry type you're dealing with. Within this field, there are all sorts of values you can override. For instance, you can point the SEO title field to one of your other fields via a dropdown, or you can manually type in a new SEO title just for this particular entry.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the SEOmatic Meta field on the page in question, as it causes an error, as there's too many rows in the database on that page once the seomatic plugin is added to it. So I've had to disable it on that page only. Rest of the site is fine. But I need to manually override the global <title> that the plugin still generates for that page. So I want to override it in the page template without the fieldtype if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok, I see. It feels like you might be trying to work around an existing problem which is just highlighted by SEOMatic. Maybe it'd be worth seeing if there was something you could do about the "too many rows" issue first. Post up another question up on here if you need a hand with that.